# reading response from telnet server c# sockets

Tags: c#, sockets, telnet

I have the following code which successfully allows me to open a socket to a telnet server and negotiate the appropriate handshake as shown below.

```
Established Connection to 192.168.10.33
FF FD 18 FF FD 20 FF FD 23 FF FD 27 FF FD 24            ÿy.ÿy.ÿy#ÿy'ÿy$
FF FB 03 FF FD 01 FF FD 22 FF FD 1F FF FB 05 FF         ÿû.ÿy.ÿy"ÿy.ÿû.ÿ
FD 21                                                   y!
FF FB 01 FF FD 06 FF FD 00                              ÿû.ÿy.ÿy.
FF FB 03 FF FB 01                                       ÿû.ÿû.
```

Where I am stuck and appear to be missing something fundamental is how to read back a continuous stream of data back from telnet after the handshake above is completed.

Here is the concept. I send a telnet command stored in an xml file and want to be able to read back the response from the telnet server as a variable I can use to display back into the console and send to other methods in the application.
See image below for clarification using putty as the client:
[image]

I am also unable to recieve the `0x0D 0x0A Welcome to the Tesira Text Protocol Server 0x0D 0x0A` welcome message, but I think this is just a symptom of the wider problem.

I am able to send the command with:

```
Console.WriteLine("Item: "+item.Attributes["commandText"].Value);
byte[] commandBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(item.Attributes["commandText"].Value + " \r\n");
s.Send(commandBytes);
```

However I am a bit lost on how to read back the data.
The code below is the class I have written to deal with the socket connection and handshake aspect.

I just don't really know where to head next, been looking around for a few hours for a good tutorial that I can understand but have had no luck in finding anything that really helps me.

```
class telnetHandshake
{
    private static byte[] writeBuffer;
    private static byte[] readBuffer;
    private static int bc;

    public void telnetInit()
    {
        IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.10.33");
        int port = 23;
        IPEndPoint endpoint = new IPEndPoint(address, port);

        Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp); 
        try
        {
            s.Connect(endpoint);
            Console.WriteLine("Established Connection to {0}", address);

            byte[] readBuffer = new byte[1024];
            bc = s.Receive(readBuffer);
            //Console.WriteLine(bc + " Bytes Found");
            DumpBytes(readBuffer, bc);

            writeBuffer = new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xFC, 0x18, 0xFF, 0xFC, 0x20, 0xFF, 0xFC, 0x23, 0xFF, 0xFC, 0x27, 0xFF, 0xFC, 0x24 };
            s.Send(writeBuffer);
            readBuffer = new byte[1024];
            bc = s.Receive(readBuffer);
            //Console.WriteLine(bc + " Bytes Found");
            DumpBytes(readBuffer, bc);

            writeBuffer = new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xFE, 0x03, 0xFF, 0xFC, 0x01, 0xFF, 0xFC, 0x22, 0xFF, 0xFC, 0x1F, 0xFF, 0xFE, 0x05, 0xFF, 0XFC, 0x21 };
            s.Send(writeBuffer);
            readBuffer = new byte[1024];
            bc = s.Receive(readBuffer);
            //Console.WriteLine(bc + " Bytes Found");
            DumpBytes(readBuffer, bc);

            writeBuffer = new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xFE, 0x01, 0xFF, 0xFC, 0x06, 0xFF, 0xFC, 0x00 };
            s.Send(writeBuffer);
            readBuffer = new byte[1024];
            bc = s.Receive(readBuffer);
            //Console.WriteLine(bc + " Bytes Found");
            DumpBytes(readBuffer, bc);

            writeBuffer = new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xFE, 0x03, 0xFF, 0xFE, 0x01 };
            s.Send(writeBuffer);

            readBuffer = new byte[1024];
            bc = s.Receive(readBuffer);
            //Console.WriteLine(bc + " Bytes Found");
            DumpBytes(readBuffer, bc);
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connection to {0} Failed!", address);
        }
    }
```

I do not want to use minimal telnet or any other library, I would like to learn how to finish off what I have started as I feel I am pretty close to getting this down to a point that it is useful for my purposes.

Comment: You probably want to use a ReadLine().  Then type in TELNET and press return.  You app will wait for the return before continuing.

Comment: @jdweng I ended up setting a readBuffer variable, checking if there were any bytes available for reading, assigning them to readBuffer var, getting the readBuffer length and finally converting the hex byte array to ASCii. Not sure quite what you meant in your response. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve my issue using the following code:

```
            if (s.Receive(readBuffer) > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(hex2string(readBuffer, s.Receive(readBuffer)));
            }
```

After the handshake completed, I just checked for any new data, if there is data available, I read it into a function which converts it from HEX to ASCII.

This approach works for me as the code snippet will be called after:

```
byte[] commandBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(item.Attributes["commandText"].Value + " \r\n");
s.Send(commandBytes);
```

so there will always be a repose waiting to be read each time a submit a new command.